# Postgresql order by array overlap

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sql-order-by

I want to sort a table with array. The record with the most overlaps should be on top. I already have a where statement to filter the records with arrays. With the same array I want to determine the number of overlaps for sorting. Do you have an idea how the order by statement might look like ?

**My Table**

```sql
SELECT * FROM "nodes"
```

```
+-----------+---------------------------+
| name      |            tags           |
+-----------+---------------------------+
| Max       | ["foo", "orange", "app"]  |
| Peter     | ["foo", "bar", "baz"]     |
| Maria     | ["foo", "bar"]            |
| John      | ["apple"]                 |
+-----------+---------------------------+
```

**Result with where**

```sql
SELECT * FROM "nodes" WHERE (tags && '{"foo", "bar", "baz"}')
```

```
+-----------+---------------------------+
| name      |            tags           |
+-----------+---------------------------+
| Max       | ["foo", "orange", "app"]  |
| Peter     | ["foo", "bar", "baz"]     |
| Maria     | ["foo", "bar"]            |
+-----------+---------------------------+
```

**Result with Order**

```sql
SELECT * FROM "nodes" WHERE (tags && '{"foo", "bar", "baz"}') ORDER BY ????
```

```
+-----------+---------------------------+
| name      |            tags           |
+-----------+---------------------------+
| Peter     | ["foo", "bar", "baz"]     |
| Maria     | ["foo", "bar"]            |
| Max       | ["foo", "orange", "app"]  |
+-----------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, is to create a function that computes the number of common elements:

```
create or replace function num_overlaps(p_one text[], p_other text[])
  returns bigint
as
$$
  select count(*)
  from (
    select *
    from unnest(p_one)
    intersect   
    select *
    from unnest(p_other)
  ) x
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then use it in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM nodes 
WHERE tags && '{"foo", "bar", "baz"}'
order by num_overlaps(tags, '{"foo", "bar", "baz"}') desc;
```

The drawback is, that you need to repeat the list of tags you are testing for.

---

It's unclear to me if those values are JSON arrays (because that's the syntax in the sample data) or native Postgres arrays (because of the `&&` operator which doesn't work for JSON arrays) - if you are using `jsonb` you can replace `unnest()` with `jsonb_array_elements_text()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the arrays are needed for the identifiers of both sides of `&&` operator, such as `STRING_TO_ARRAY(translate(tags::text, '[] "', ''), ',')::text[]` instead of `tags` and `STRING_TO_ARRAY('foo,bar,baz',','))` instead of `'{"foo", "bar", "baz"}'` pattern, respectively.

Then, you can unnest array elements for tags column by using `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` function in order to count the occurence of each elements of returned `value` columns within `'{"foo", "bar", "baz"}'` pattern through use of `STRPOS()` and `SIGN()` functions together with `SUM()` aggregation :

```
SELECT name, tags::text
  FROM "nodes" 
 CROSS JOIN JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(tags) AS js
 WHERE ( STRING_TO_ARRAY(translate(tags::text, '[] "', ''), ',')::text[] 
      && STRING_TO_ARRAY('foo,bar,baz',','))
 GROUP BY name, tags::text    
 ORDER BY SUM( SIGN( STRPOS('{"foo", "bar", "baz"}'::text,value::text) ) ) DESC
```

But, you may have repeated elements within `tags` column. In this case the above query fails. So, I suggest to use this one below containing rows eliminated by `DISTINCT` keyword :

```
SELECT name, tags 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT name, tags::text, STRPOS('{"foo", "bar", "baz"}'::text,value::text)
     FROM "nodes" 
    CROSS JOIN JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(tags) AS js
    WHERE ( STRING_TO_ARRAY(translate(tags::text, '[] "', ''), ',')::text[] 
         && STRING_TO_ARRAY('foo,bar,baz',','))
  ) n    
  GROUP BY name, tags::text    
  ORDER BY SUM( SIGN( strpos ) ) DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2b2116c9cfab1151329a882eaffd77e5)</kbd>